# Can't get all html code by using execute_script in Python for web scraping

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get html code for web scraping using Python. I chose a website of the real estate agency.

Before doing onclick event of the button that change pages I need to get this element itself. 
However buttons that let us go to the next or previous page (designed with symbols ">" and "<") are not displayed inside the code.

Could you please advice something on this issue.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.centris.ca/en/properties~for-sale?view=Thumbnail"
browser.get(url)

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
print(innerHTML)
```

Comment: just use the built-in method `html_source = browser.page_source` instead of using javascript

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same output missing buttons ">" and "<".Here it is:         <li class="previous inactive">
            <a>&nbsp;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pager-current">1 / 3,577</li>
        <li class="next">
            <a>&nbsp;</a>

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You simply need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be visible* and then extract the **html** / **page source** as follows:

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.centris.ca/en/properties~for-sale?view=Thumbnail")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wrapper.even.wrapper-results")))
print(driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML"))
```

Console Output:

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-558V6M" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>        <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->


    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NC4N8H6" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>        <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

    <div id="site" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Centris.ca">
    <meta content="https://www.facebook.com/centris.ca/" itemprop="sameAs">
    <meta content="Centris.ca lists all of the properties for sale or rent by a real estate broker in Québec. Find your house, condo, lot, plex, business..." itemprop="description">

    <header id="header">
        <div id="header-wrapper" class="wrapper">

        <div class="top-nav" role="navigation">
            <a class="logo-container" itemprop="url" href="/en">
            <img itemprop="logo" src="/master/images/logo-centris-small.gif" alt="Centris.ca">
            <strong>The Largest Number of Homes for Sale</strong>
            </a>
            <nav class="menu-container">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li>
                <a class="main-item" href="/en/buy">Buy</a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul class="purchase">
                    <li class="first"><a href="/en/properties~for-sale?view=Thumbnail&amp;OpenSearchPanel=true" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Find a property</span></a></li>
                    <li class="second"><a href="/en/buy/buying-with-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Buying with a broker</span></a></li>
                    <li class="third"><a href="/en/buy/house-buying-process" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Steps involved in buying</span></a></li>
                    <li class="fourth"><a href="/en/buy/risks-buying-without-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Risks of buying without a broker</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a class="main-item" href="/en/sell">Sell</a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul class="sale">
                    <li class="first"><a href="/en/sell/selling-your-house" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Selling with a broker</span></a></li>
                    <li class="second"><a href="/en/sell/house-selling-process" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Steps involved in selling</span></a></li>
                    <li class="third"><a href="/en/sell/risks-selling-without-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Risks of selling without a broker</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a class="main-item" href="/en/my-real-estate-broker">My broker</a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul class="broker">
                    <li class="first"><a href="/en/real-estate-brokers" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Find a broker</span></a></li>
                    <li class="second"><a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/why-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">The role of the broker</span></a></li>
                    <li class="third"><a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/how-choose-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">The 10 qualities of a good broker</span></a></li>
                    <li class="fifth"><a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/testimonials" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">What clients are saying</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/become-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Become a broker</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a class="main-item" href="/en/tools">Tools</a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul class="infos">
                    <li class="first"><a href="/en/tools/community-profile" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Community profile</span></a></li>
                    <li class="second"><a href="/en/tools/real-estate-statistics" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Real estate statistics</span></a></li>
                    <li class="third"><a href="/en/tools/useful-links" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Useful links</span></a></li>
                    <li class="fourth"><a href="/en/blog" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Real estate blog</span></a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="/en/tools/calculator" class="enableHover"><span class="item-title">Calculator</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="property-search-icon"><a href="/en/properties~for-sale?view=Thumbnail&amp;OpenSearchPanel=true" class=" current">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right-menu">
                <li class="my-position-link"><a href="/en/properties~for-sale?view=Map&amp;geolocalization=enabled"><i></i>Nearby</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/en/login?returnUrl=%2fen%2fproperties%7efor-sale%3fview%3dThumbnail">My account</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                <a class="lang" href="/fr/propriete~a-vendre?view=Thumbnail"><span class="desktop">FR</span><span class="device">Français</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="last-child">
                <a class="btn-favorites favorites " href="/en/my-favourites?view=Thumbnail" title="See my favourites">
                    <span class="icon icon-fav enableHover"></span>
                    <span class="text">Favourites</span>

                    <span class="labelCount hidden"></span>

                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav>
            <ul class="mobile-menu-container">

                <li class="border">
                    <a href="/en/login?returnUrl=%2fen%2fproperties%7efor-sale%3fview%3dThumbnail">My account</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                <div class="m-favorites">
                    <a class="m-fav-link link-disabled" href="/en/my-favourites?view=Thumbnail" title="See my favourites">
                    <span class="text">My favourites</span>&nbsp;
                    <span class="labelCount hidden"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="border">
                <a href="/en/properties~for-sale?view=Map&amp;geolocalization=enabled">Nearby</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="main-item">Buy</div>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/properties~for-sale?view=Thumbnail&amp;OpenSearchPanel=true" class="enableHover">Find a property</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/buy/buying-with-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover">Buying with a broker</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/buy/house-buying-process" class="enableHover">Steps involved in buying</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/buy/risks-buying-without-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover">Risks of buying without a broker</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="main-item">Sell</div>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/sell/selling-your-house" class="enableHover">Selling with a broker</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/sell/house-selling-process" class="enableHover">Steps involved in selling</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/sell/risks-selling-without-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover">Risks of selling without a broker</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="main-item">My broker</div>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/real-estate-brokers" class="enableHover">Find a broker</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/why-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover">The role of the broker</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/how-choose-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover">The 10 qualities of a good broker</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/testimonials" class="enableHover">What clients are saying</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/my-real-estate-broker/become-real-estate-broker" class="enableHover">Become a broker</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="border">
                <div class="main-item">Tools</div>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/tools/community-profile" class="enableHover">Community profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/tools/real-estate-statistics" class="enableHover">Real estate statistics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/tools/useful-links" class="enableHover">Useful links</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/blog" class="enableHover">Real estate blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/en/tools/calculator" class="enableHover">Calculator</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="border">
                <a class="lang" href="/fr/propriete~a-vendre?view=Thumbnail">Français</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="https://secure.centris.ca/authentification.aspx?application=183c99ed-a64a-4559-8fc2-0187fc233773&amp;langue=en">Broker login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="mobileMenuButtons">
            <a class="searchLink icon-search" href="/en/properties~for-sale?view=Thumbnail&amp;OpenSearchPanel=true" aria-label="Search"></a>
            <div class="menuToggle icon-menu " aria-label="Toggle navigation"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


<div id="search-block" role="search" class="region" style="display: none">
    <div id="search-form">
    <fieldset>
        <fieldset class="search-field">
        <div class="ie-search fields-container">
            <label id="labelSearch" for="search">Search by City, Neighbourhood, Region, Address or Centris<sup>®</sup> No.</label>
            <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="focus ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <button id="submit-search" class="btn btn-search">Search</button>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="freeform-filters" class="filters-list">
        <ul></ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Price -->
        <fieldset id="price" class="fieldset">
        <legend class="none">Price</legend>
        <div class="control-group slide">
            <div class="controls">
            <div id="slider" data-min-price="0" data-max-price="999999999" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false"><div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 100%;"></a></div>
            <div id="slider-value"><span id="currentPrixMin" data-value="0" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">$0</span><span id="currentPrixMax" data-value="999999999" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span>$20,000,000+</span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <!-- Residentiel/Commerciel, Vendre/Louer -->
        <fieldset id="property-category" class="fieldset">
        <legend class="none">Catégorie</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-radio first">
            <button id="residentiel" class="btn btn-check active">Residential</button>
            <button id="commercial" class="btn btn-check">Commercial</button>
            </div>
            <div class="control-radio">
            <button id="avendre" class="btn btn-check active">For sale</button>
            <button id="alouer" class="btn btn-check">For rent</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <a id="btn-advanced-criterias" class="link-more-below" href="javascript:;" style="display: none;">ADVANCED CRITERIA<i></i></a>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="container-advanced-criterias">

        <!-- PropertyTypes  -->
        <fieldset class="fieldset fieldset-border" id="LegendItemProperty">
        <legend class="none">Property type<i class="btn-toggle"></i></legend>
        <div id="item-property" class="control-select-inline container-fieldset">
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="A">Single-family home</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="B">Condo</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="C">Loft / Studio</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="D">Condominium home</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="E">Plex</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="F">Intergenerational</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="G">Mobile home</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="H">Hobby farm</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="I">Lot</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="J" style="display: none;">Multi-Family</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="K" style="display: none;">Office</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="L" style="display: none;">Industrial</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="M" style="display: none;">Commercial</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="N" style="display: none;">Accommodation</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="O" style="display: none;">Agricultural</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="P" style="display: none;">Lot</button>
            <button class="btn-form-choice" data-value="Q" style="display: none;">Business</button>
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <!-- FEATURES SECTION -->
        <fieldset class="fieldset-border" id="CharacteristicsSection">
        <legend>Features<i class="btn-toggle"></i></legend>

        <div class="container-fieldset">
            <!-- DROPDOWNS - FEATURES SECTION -->
            <fieldset id="fdChambreStat">
            <legend></legend>
            <div class="control-group caracteristics">
                <div class="controls">
                <!-- Chambres  -->
                <div class="control-select" id="select-room" tabindex="-1" data-visiblity-name="Rooms"> <div class="selectarea" tabindex="-1">   <div class="arrow" style="">    <b style=""></b>   </div> <div class="text" style=""><span class="singleSelectSpan">Number of bedrooms</span>  </div>     </div>
                    <div class="dropdown" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="option active" data-option-value="0">Number of bedrooms</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="1">1 bedroom</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="1+">1 bedroom or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="2">2 bedrooms</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="2+">2 bedrooms or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="3">3 bedrooms</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="3+">3 bedrooms or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="4">4 bedrooms</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="4+">4 bedrooms or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="5">5 bedrooms</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="5+">5 bedrooms or +</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Salle de bain/eau -->
                <div class="control-select" id="select-bathroom" tabindex="-1" data-visiblity-name="Bathrooms"> <div class="selectarea" tabindex="-1">   <div class="arrow" style="">    <b style=""></b>   </div> <div class="text" style=""><span class="singleSelectSpan">Number of bath/powder rooms</span>  </div>     </div>
                    <div class="dropdown" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="option active" data-option-value="0">Number of bath/powder rooms</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="1">1 bath/powder room or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="2">2 bath/powder rooms or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="3">3 bath/powder rooms or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="4">4 bath/powder rooms or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="5">5 bath/powder rooms or +</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Stationnement  -->
                <div class="control-select" id="select-stationnement" tabindex="-1" data-visiblity-name="Stationnement"> <div class="selectarea" tabindex="-1">   <div class="arrow" style="">    <b style=""></b>   </div> <div class="text" style=""><span class="singleSelectSpan">Number of parking spaces</span>  </div>     </div>
                    <div class="dropdown" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="option active" data-option-value="0">Number of parking spaces</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="1">1 parking or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="2">2 parkings or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="3">3 parkings or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="4">4 parkings or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="5">5 parkings or +</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Garage -->
                <div class="control-select" id="select-garage" tabindex="-1" data-visiblity-name="Garage"> <div class="selectarea" tabindex="-1">   <div class="arrow" style="">    <b style=""></b>   </div> <div class="text" style=""><span class="singleSelectSpan">Number of garages</span>  </div>     </div>
                    <div class="dropdown" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="option active" data-option-value="0">Number of garages</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="1">1 garage or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="2">2 garages or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="3">3 garages or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="4">4 garages or +</li>
                        <li class="option" data-option-value="5">5 garages or +</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <!-- CHECKBOXS - FEATURES SECTION  -->
            <fieldset id="fsCaracAutre">
            <legend></legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <ul class="checkbox-list">
                <!-- Specs -->
                <li data-visiblity-name="Piscine">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-piscine"><i></i><label for="chk-piscine" class="checkbox">Pool<span id="spanchk-piscine"></span></label>
                </li>
                <li data-visiblity-name="Ascenseur">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-ascenseur"><i></i><label for="chk-ascenseur" class="checkbox">Elevator<span id="spanchk-ascenseur"></span></label>
                </li>
                <li data-visiblity-name="Apmr">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-apmr"><i></i><label for="chk-apmr" class="checkbox">Adapted for reduced mobility<span id="spanchk-apmr"></span></label>
                </li>


                <li data-visiblity-name="BordEau">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-bordeau"><i></i><label for="chk-bordeau" class="checkbox">Waterfront<span id="spanchk-bordeau"></span></label>
                </li>
                <li data-visiblity-name="AccesEau">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-acceseau"><i></i><label for="chk-acceseau" class="checkbox">Access to waterfront<span id="spanchk-acceseau"></span></label>
                </li>
                <li data-visiblity-name="PlanEauNavigable">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-planeaunavigable"><i></i><label for="chk-planeaunavigable" class="checkbox">Navigable body of water<span id="spanchk-planeaunavigable"></span></label>
                </li>


                <li data-visiblity-name="Meuble" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-meuble"><i></i><label for="chk-meuble" class="checkbox">Furnished<span id="spanchk-meuble"></span></label>
                </li>
                <li data-visiblity-name="SemiMeuble" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk-semimeuble"><i></i><label for="chk-semimeuble" class="checkbox">Semi-furnished<span id="spanchk-semimeuble"></span></label>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset data-visiblity-name="TypeHebergement" style="display: none;">
            <legend></legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <ul id="type-hebergement" class="checkbox-list controls checkboxes">
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="HOTEL" data-value="HOTEL"><i></i><label for="HOTEL" class="checkbox">Hotel<span id="spanTypeHebergementHOTEL"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="MOTEL" data-value="MOTEL"><i></i><label for="MOTEL" class="checkbox">Motel<span id="spanTypeHebergementMOTEL"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AUBERGE" data-value="AUBERGE"><i></i><label for="AUBERGE" class="checkbox">Inn<span id="spanTypeHebergementAUBERGE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="MAISONRETR" data-value="MAISONRETR"><i></i><label for="MAISONRETR" class="checkbox">Seniors' residence<span id="spanTypeHebergementMAISONRETR"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AU" data-value="AU"><i></i><label for="AU" class="checkbox">Other<span id="spanTypeHebergementAU"></span></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset data-visiblity-name="TypeExploitation" style="display: none;">
            <legend></legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <ul id="type-exploitation" class="checkbox-list controls checkboxes">
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ELEVAGE" data-value="ELEVAGE"><i></i><label for="ELEVAGE" class="checkbox">Animal husbandry<span id="spanTypeExploitationELEVAGE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="APICULTURE" data-value="APICULTURE"><i></i><label for="APICULTURE" class="checkbox">Beekeeping<span id="spanTypeExploitationAPICULTURE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="FERMELAIT" data-value="FERMELAIT"><i></i><label for="FERMELAIT" class="checkbox">Dairy farm<span id="spanTypeExploitationFERMELAIT"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="SERRES" data-value="SERRES"><i></i><label for="SERRES" class="checkbox">Greenhouses<span id="spanTypeExploitationSERRES"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="HORTICOLE" data-value="HORTICOLE"><i></i><label for="HORTICOLE" class="checkbox">Horticulture<span id="spanTypeExploitationHORTICOLE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ERABLIERE" data-value="ERABLIERE"><i></i><label for="ERABLIERE" class="checkbox">Maple forest<span id="spanTypeExploitationERABLIERE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="PEPINIERE" data-value="PEPINIERE"><i></i><label for="PEPINIERE" class="checkbox">Nursery (tree)<span id="spanTypeExploitationPEPINIERE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="VERGER" data-value="VERGER"><i></i><label for="VERGER" class="checkbox">Orchard<span id="spanTypeExploitationVERGER"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="EQUESTRE" data-value="EQUESTRE"><i></i><label for="EQUESTRE" class="checkbox">Riding centre<span id="spanTypeExploitationEQUESTRE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="MARAICHERE" data-value="MARAICHERE"><i></i><label for="MARAICHERE" class="checkbox">Vegetable farm<span id="spanTypeExploitationMARAICHERE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="VIGNOBLE" data-value="VIGNOBLE"><i></i><label for="VIGNOBLE" class="checkbox">Winery<span id="spanTypeExploitationVIGNOBLE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AU" data-value="AU"><i></i><label for="AU" class="checkbox">Other<span id="spanTypeExploitationAU"></span></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset data-visiblity-name="Zonage" style="display: none;">
            <div class="control-group">
                <ul id="zonage" class="checkbox-list controls checkboxes">
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="RESI" data-value="RESI"><i></i><label for="RESI" class="checkbox">Residential zoning<span id="spanZonageRESI"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="COMM" data-value="COMM"><i></i><label for="COMM" class="checkbox">Commercial zoning<span id="spanZonageCOMM"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="INDS" data-value="INDS"><i></i><label for="INDS" class="checkbox">Industrial zoning<span id="spanZonageINDS"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AGR" data-value="AGR"><i></i><label for="AGR" class="checkbox">Agricultural zoning<span id="spanZonageAGR"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="FORE" data-value="FORE"><i></i><label for="FORE" class="checkbox">Forest zoning<span id="spanZonageFORE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="VILG" data-value="VILG"><i></i><label for="VILG" class="checkbox">Resort zoning<span id="spanZonageVILG"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="RECR" data-value="RECR"><i></i><label for="RECR" class="checkbox">Recreational and tourism zoning<span id="spanZonageRECR"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AUT" data-value="AUT"><i></i><label for="AUT" class="checkbox">Other zoning<span id="spanZonageAUT"></span></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset data-visiblity-name="SecteurActivite" style="display: none;">
            <div class="control-group">
                <ul id="secteur-activite" class="checkbox-list controls checkboxes">
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ALIM" data-value="ALIM"><i></i><label for="ALIM" class="checkbox">Food services<span id="spanSecteurActiviteALIM"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="REST" data-value="REST"><i></i><label for="REST" class="checkbox">Restaurant industry<span id="spanSecteurActiviteREST"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="HEBERGEMENT" data-value="HEBERGEMENT"><i></i><label for="HEBERGEMENT" class="checkbox">Accomodation<span id="spanSecteurActiviteHEBERGEMENT"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="VENDET" data-value="VENDET"><i></i><label for="VENDET" class="checkbox">Retail Sales<span id="spanSecteurActiviteVENDET"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="SERVICE" data-value="SERVICE"><i></i><label for="SERVICE" class="checkbox">Service<span id="spanSecteurActiviteSERVICE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="FAB" data-value="FAB"><i></i><label for="FAB" class="checkbox">Manufacturing<span id="spanSecteurActiviteFAB"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AGRICOLE" data-value="AGRICOLE"><i></i><label for="AGRICOLE" class="checkbox">Agricultural<span id="spanSecteurActiviteAGRICOLE"></span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AU" data-value="AU"><i></i><label for="AU" class="checkbox">Other<span id="spanSecteurActiviteAU"></span></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset data-visiblity-name="GenreCommerce" style="display: none;">
            <div class="field-focus">
                <label for="genre-commerce">Type of business</label>
                <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><input id="genre-commerce" class="focus dropdown ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
                <div id="genreCommerce-filters" class="filters-list">
                <ul></ul>
                </div>
                <ul style="display:none"></ul>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same output missing buttons ">" and "<".Here it is:         <li class="previous inactive">
            <a>&nbsp;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pager-current">1 / 3,577</li>
        <li class="next">
            <a>&nbsp;</a>

Answer (score 0):

One can click a link without seeing its content simply by using following line of code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='next']/a").click()
```